# Update some (not all) post titles with custom field values before running the Loop

Tags: custom-field

In this project, there are custom posts with a variety of titles. In each post with the title that is the name of a person (first name, last name), there is a custom field (custom_title) that can hold an alternate name (last name, first name).

In order to display the names in a useful way in the custom archive page, the object is to check for a value in the custom_title field and if present update the post title with the custom title. After all of the applicable titles have been updated, the query must sort all of the posts by title, all the while recognizing the updated titles.

Using the code below, the original titles of the name articles are updated with the custom titles, but the sort order doesn't change--it still sorts by the original title.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

```
    function cchs_swap_title( $updatedTitle) 
    {
        $customTitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_title', true);
        if(!empty($customTitle))
        {
            $updatedTitle = $customTitle;
        }
        return $updatedTitle;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'cchs_swap_title');
    
    function cchs_archives_orderby( $the_query ) {
        if(!is_admin() && $the_query->is_main_query())
        {
            $the_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            $the_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
            
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cchs_archives_orderby', 99999 );      

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'cchs_article',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive-cchs_article');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are querying all posts at once with `'posts_per_page'=> -1` it would be easiest to get all posts as an array, update title if needed, and sort them after.

The disadvantage of that approach is you would have to update your loop to use properties instead of functions i.e. instead of `the_title();` you would use `echo $article->post_title;` Example below would work **without** the `cchs_swap_title` filter and `cchs_archives_orderby` action.

```php
$args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'cchs_article',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$articles = $the_query->get_posts(); // Get all the posts as an array

// Update post title based on custom field
foreach ( $articles as $article ) {
    $customTitle = get_post_meta( $article->ID, 'custom_title', true);
    if( $customTitle ) {
        $article->post_title = $customTitle;
    }
}

// Sort all posts by title
usort($articles, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp( $a->post_title, $b->post_title );
} );

// The loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    foreach ( $articles as $article ) {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'archive-cchs_article', [ 'article' => $article ] );
    }
else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif;
```

In the above example inside the template part file instead of `the_title()` you would need to use `echo $args['article']->post_title;`.

The `$args['article']` is the article we pass as 3rd argument in `get_template_part` function.

Comment: The objective was to use existing WP functions, if at all possible, but hours of scouring the web and the extensive WP documentation to that end yielded no solutions. YOUR solution, on the other hand, does the job very well and will be the one that is implemented. Thank you again, @Greg36, for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach: create post meta value with the title when the article is created or updated. This way we always have the final title saved and we can sort by it right away.

To do this hook to `save_post`, check if current post is an article and update the `true_title` meta value with custom field's value or with post title if that one is empty.

```php
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_397145_save_proper_title', 10, 2 );

function wpse_397145_save_proper_title( $post_id, $post ) {
    // Only check in articles
    if ( 'cchs_article' !== $post->post_type ) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the final title to custom field, default to the post title
    $customTitle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_title', true);
    if( ! $customTitle ) {
        $customTitle = $post->post_title;
    }
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'true_title', $customTitle );
}
```

Now just change the WP_Query args to (you can even skip -1 here):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    'post_type'      => 'cchs_article',
    'meta_key'       => 'true_title',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
);
```

And last, where you use `the_title()` for the article, replace it with `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'true_title', true);` to output the correct title right away.

Comment: This solution threw a WordPress critical error. Nevertheless, thank you very much for taking the time to try to help.

Comment: I've checked the code on a fresh install and it worked, try turning on debug mode - https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ - if you work locally and tell me what was the error. Oh and I made a typo in the WP_Query args example where I had "product" instead of "cchs_article" as the post_type.

Comment: Thank you for the debug mode suggestion. A comma was missing after the first line in the $args array. The addition of the comma fixed the error. Unfortunately, the result set returned Nothing Found.

Comment: @P.Britten In this method the "true_title" used to sort and echo is set when a new article is created or updated. Try creating a new article or just open one in the admin and just save. And check if you have the correct "post_type", set to "cchs_article".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately, that suggestion cannot be used in this project: the number of articles would make it unwieldy, and opening and saving would change the public-facing date of update. The client would not accept that. Thank you again for all of your time and effort. It is much appreciated.